# Mock & Stub System.getProperty , Mockito cannot mock/spy because 'final' class

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I got this error while mock java.lang.System

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot mock/spy class java.lang.System
Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
 - final class
```

What my code like :

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(System.class)
public class UaUtilsTest {

    @Mock
    Context context;

    @Mock
    PackageManager packageManager;

    @Mock
    PackageInfo packageInfo;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
        when(System.getProperty("http.agent")).thenReturn("user agent");
    }
```

I already try :
 1. Using PowerMockito to Mock Static
 2. Stub getProperty method calls

Is there any solution to this error?

Comment: Most likely no. Static methods break testing. If you're using a DI framework, normally you would inject that as configuration, rather than do a static method lookup, to avoid this exact problem

Comment: You can use `System.setProperty("http.agent", user agent");` in a static block in the test class, no need to mock at all. Just be careful of test pollution, maybe set it back to its start value after. Not sure if anything else would ever use it in tests.